# Makefile with multiple values for a parameter

Tags: makefile

Currently, I am working on a makefile that takes a parameter "CLASS=xxx" and then compiles and does stuff with that value.
In the end, it runs an application ($APP) on a bunch of files.

I enter this command:

```
make default CLASS=Test_UART
```

and the makefile processes it thusly:

```
pc: $(APP)
    make -C BUILDENV CLASS=$(CLASS) BUILD=just_filelist OUTPUT=filelist.txt SKIPSELF=yes
    ../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(CLASS).class> ./Applications/$(CLASS).ujc
    time -p ./$(APP) ./Applications/$(CLASS).ujc `cat filelist.txt`
```

Hence it calls a makefile in my BUILDENV folder which does the following:

```
#USAGE:  make -C <PATH_TO_THIS_FILES_PARENT_DIR> CLASS=<MY_JAVA_FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_JAVA_EXTENSION> OUT=<OUTPUT_FILE_NAME>


SELF    := $(dir $(CURDIR)/$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
CLASS   ?= PLEASE_SPECIFY_CLASS_PARAM
DIR     := $(PWD)#print working directory
CCVT    ?= $(SELF)/../../classCvt/classCvt
TOBIN   ?= $(SELF)/../../classCvt/tobin
OUTPUT  ?= 

### Comment: Defining CMD.
ifeq ($(BUILD), just_filelist)
    CMD = echo
else
    ifeq ($(BUILD), PC)
        CMD = echo
    else
        ifeq ($(BUILD), unopt)

            CMD = $(TOBIN)
        else
            ### Comment: Optimized CMD = tobin -c ccvt
            CMD = $(TOBIN) -c $(CCVT)
        endif
    endif
endif

ifeq ($(OUTPUT), )
    OUT = &1
else
    OUT = $(DIR)/$(OUTPUT)
endif

ifeq ($(SKIPSELF), yes)
    MYCLASS = 
else
    MYCLASS = $(DIR)/Applications/$(CLASS).class
endif

all:
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/RT/real:$(SELF)/RT/fake:$(DIR) javac $(DIR)/Applications/$(CLASS).java
    find $(SELF)/RT/real -iname "*.class" -type f > $(SELF)/files
    ls $(DIR)/Applications/*.class | grep -v "$(CLASS)\.class" >> $(SELF)/files || true
    cat $(SELF)/files | xargs $(CMD) $(MYCLASS) >$(OUT)
    rm -f $(SELF)/files
```

What I would like to do is give a command like:

```
make default CLASS=Test1,Test2,Test3
```

and the makefile to process it for the 3 classes and put the given classes in a .txt and the default classes in a different .txt, something like this like this:

```
pc: $(APP)
    make -C BUILDENV default_classes BUILD=list_default_classes OUTPUT=list_default_classes.txt
#   make -C BUILDENV given_classes BUILD=list_given_classes OUTPUT=list_given_classes.txt CLASS=$(CLASS) SKIPSELF=yes
    ../classCvt/classCvt `cat list_given_classes.txt`./Applications/$(CLASS).ujc
    #here the list_given_classes should now contain the .ujc files
    time -p ./$(APP) `cat list_given_classes.txt` `cat list_default_classes.txt`
```

and for the makefile in the BUILDENV, I expect something like:

```
default_classes:
        CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/RT/real:$(SELF)/RT/fake:$(DIR) 
        find $(SELF)/RT/real -iname "*.class" -type f > $(SELF)/files
        ls $(DIR)/Applications/*.class | grep -v "$(CLASS1)\.class" "$(CLASS2)\.class">> $(SELF)/files || true
        cat $(SELF)/files | xargs $(CMD) >$(OUT)
        rm -f $(SELF)/files

given_classes:
    javac $(DIR)/Applications/$(CLASS).java
    find $(SELF)/RT/real -iname "*.class" -type f > $(SELF)/files
    ls $(DIR)/Applications/*.class | grep -v "$(CLASS)\.class" >> $(SELF)/files || true
    cat $(SELF)/files | xargs $(CMD) $(MYCLASS) >$(OUT)
    rm -f $(SELF)/files
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this for a CLASS parameter containing multiple classes. 
I'm thinking to try and parse the Test1,Test2,Test3 value into a list of 1,2,3 and then iterating over it. But no clue if this is a good way and even on how to do it.
What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty way:

```
pc: $(APP)

define BUILD_CLASS

pc: pc-$(CLASS_SPLIT)

pc-$(CLASS_SPLIT):
    make -C BUILDENV CLASS=$(CLASS_SPLIT) BUILD=just_filelist OUTPUT=filelist.txt SKIPSELF=yes
    ../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(CLASS_SPLIT).class> ./Applications/$(CLASS_SPLIT).ujc
    time -p ./$(APP) ./Applications/$(CLASS_SPLIT).ujc `cat filelist.txt`

endef

CLASSES := $(shell echo $(CLASS) | tr ',' ' ')

$(foreach CLASS_SPLIT, $(CLASSES), $(eval $(BUILD_CLASS)))
```

Comment: It doesn't work fully yet (possibly due to errors on my side) but it is sufficient to continue. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, addendum: Small oversight in the above code, it should be:

    ../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(CLASS_SPLIT).class> ./Applications/$(CLASS_SPLIT).ujc


instead of

    ../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(CLASS_SPLIT).class> ./Applications/$(CLASS).ujc

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
pc: $(APP)
    $(foreach C, $(shell echo $(CLASS) | tr ',' ' '), \
    make -C BUILDENV CLASS=$(C) BUILD=just_filelist OUTPUT=filelist.txt SKIPSELF=yes && \
    ../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(C).class> ./Applications/$(C).ujc && \
    time -p ./$(APP) ./Applications/$(C).ujc `cat filelist.txt` &&) true
```